# How to safely copy a global object to a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I have a header class that contains a declaration of a inline variable that I'm using as a global variable. I want to make a copy of this variable every time I call a function.

globalitems.h

```
#ifndef GLOBALVAR_H
#define GLOBALVAR_H

struct Data {
    int a; 
    Data(int ca) {
       a = ca;
    }
};

inline Data globaldata(3);

#endif
```

Otherclass.h

```
#include "globalitems.h"

void createPointerCopy() {
    Data* tempPointer = &globaldata;
    tempPointer->a = 30;
    std::cout << tempPointer->a << std::endl;
    std::cout << globaldata.a << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    createPointerCopy();
    return 0;
}
```

outputs

> 30
>
> 30

Whereas my desired output is

> 30
>
> 3

How can I make it so that `createCopy()` safely creates a copy of the `globaldata` object?

Comment: Perhaps you actually want to create a copy of the object original pointer points to, not of the global variable?

Comment: @user7860670 yes that would be better. I have edited the question to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well, what you want is not getting a pointer to your global object but you want to create a copy, that is:

```
void createPointerCopy() {
    Data temp = globaldata;
    temp.a = 30;
    std::cout << temp.a << std::endl;
    std::cout << globaldata.a << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I think your problem is that both variables point to the same place in memory.
What you really tell compiler to do with:

```
  Data* tempPointer = &globaldata;
```

is to take address of globaldata and assign it to tempPointer. Thus, by changing fields of tempPointer, you change fields globaldata. Or, in other words, (*tempPointer) becomes an alias to globaldata.
I see two options:

```
 Data tempData = globaldata;
```

and provide copy constructor if necessary; Or just:

```
 int tempVal = globaldata.a
```

Additionally, I think you may want to be introduced with [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)